# Display or highlight invisible zero width characters in (neo)vim

Tags: vim, unicode, neovim

How can I display zero width characters in (neo)vim? For example take this line:

```
This is ㅤsome textㅤ
```

... which actually has a zero width character before `some`:

```
This is \u3164some textㅤ
```

When I copy and paste the first line into my vim editor it is not displayed:

[image: vim example screenshot]

(It actually messes up the cursor, too: character count seems to be wrong and color column is offset.)

How can I make such zero width characters visible in (neo)vim? Is this possible?

It think it would be enough to display it as a question mark or maybe as ☒ or something, so it should actually *not* be zero width but be single width.

Update 11.11.2021:

I'm using NVIM v0.5.1 on MacOS 12.0.1 and iTerm2 as a terminal emulator.

Comment: No amount of `:syntax` worked, here, which is not really surprising.

Comment: Both Vim and Neovim show me these invisible characters (copied the first line from firefox, pasted with `"+p`, also works with shift+insert), with a label of "HF" in a little box, gVim does as well. I feel like this might be a terminal emulator problem, but I don't know what exactly. I use linux, and it works for me with both urxvt, and gnome-terminal.

It might be useful to report your OS and the terminal you're using, maybe how you paste it as well (

Comment: I'm using NVIM v0.5.1 on MacOS 12.0.1 and iTerm2 as a terminal emulator. I checked it in normal terminal.app, too, but the result is the same.